# lightweight Asp.net mvc based cms

Tags: asp.net-mvc

looking for a cms written in asp.net for company project collaboration
dotnetnuke is very heavy weight looking for something simple like blog engine .net but with forums wiki (and or social networking features)

any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

The [Orchard Project](http://www.orchardproject.net/) is a new open source CMS built on ASP.NET MVC being lead by a group at Microsoft.

It's still in its early phases, though, and there are no official builds yet. You can, however, download the source code and give it a shot. I've seen demos of it and it looks quite good so far.

Comment: Orchard looks like a good choice for a full blown CMS site, but I wouldn't call it lightweight.  It's based on NHibernate, Autofac and Castle.

Answer (score 1):

Check out N2 - the MVC part is not ported - there are demos for ASP.NET.

Also check out KOOBOO - it's built as an MVC app.

Good Luck !